# Ubuntu plus whonix

Tags: ubuntu, whonix

I have a dual boot Ubuntu 12.04 and Windows 7 Professionl 32 bit. Is it possible to install Whonix OS inside of Ubuntu? Or.. LXDE OS inside Ubuntu? Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Clarification: LXDE is _not_ an OS, you can install it just like any other program. Just run `sudo apt-get install lxde`. See [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LXDE) for more.

Answer (score 1):

If you've never utilized a virtual machine software product such as VirtualBox or KVM, getting started can be a little daunting, but one you get the basic ideas down and the concepts it's rather simple.

I'd encourage you to start with these tutorials from the Ubuntu website:

- [VirtualBox Community Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox)
- [VirtualBox/FirstVM](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox/FirstVM)

The screenshots are a bit dated but the gist is all there. This [one might also be of use](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Ubuntu-on-VirtualBox), it shows the installation of Ubuntu using VirtualBox on Windows but the concepts are all applicable.

The trickiest thing about setting up a VM when you're first starting out is how do you install the OS using a downloaded ISO of your particular Linux distro. The secret is this. Here's VirualBox's main window.

[image: ss of VB1]

After you've gone through and created a "New" VM you'll need to attach the ISO to the VM so that you can boot it, in the same way you'd boot an actual physical machine. Notice in the screenshot below, that if you select the VM, and then select it's setting menu (right click on the VM's name and select "Settings") you'll get to the screenshot below.

[image: ss of VB2]

From here you'll want to select the VM's "Storage" settings (**#1**) and then select the empty CD/DVD device (**#2**). Don't get confused, in the screenshot it says "debian..." that's because I already have the ISO loaded.

In **#3** you'll click the little CD/DVD icon which opens up a menu where you can do as in **#4** and select a virtual CD/DVD disk file, i.e. an ISO file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can run Whonix (or, for that matter, any other Linux distro) inside a virtual machine like [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org).